# IBM Datastage - Join Stage not doing Exact match?

Tags: left-join, sql-like, datastage

We are using IBM Datastage to match data coming via extracts from various mainframes.

One of the steps is to remove data in Oracle tables that are coming down in the extracts that night and it uses the Join stage to match an extract from an Oracle table against a dataset created from one of the extracts.

The issue is that the Join doesn't seem to do an exact match, it's like it'd using a LIKE using the keys.

Has anyone seen this before?

Example of Data:

Oracle Extract

```
POLICY_NUMBER SQL Type(VarChar) Extended(Unicode) Length(13)

POLICY_NUMBER CLIENT_NUMBER
A 123456      12345
A 123456W     A 123456W01
A 234567      23456
A 234567J     A 234567J01
```

Nightly Extract

```
POLICY_NUMBER SQL Type(Char) Extended(Unicode) Length(8)

POLICY_NUMBER PRODUCT
A 123456      LIFE
A 234567      PENSION
```

Dataset after join

```
POLICY_NUMBER CLIENT_NUMBER
A 123456      12345
A 123456      A 123456W01
A 234567      23456
A 234567      A 234567J01
```

Comment: I have not seen this before. What is the data type and length of your Policy_Number columns?

Comment: The nightly extract dataset is as follows: `POLICY_NUMBER SQL Type(Char) Extended(Unicode) Length(8)`. The Oracle table extract is as follows: `POLICY_NUMBER SQL Type(VarChar) Extended(Unicode) Length(13)`

Comment: I have basically spent the whole day messing with this job in our batch but I cannot get it to stop using the LIKE command. I have changed the types and lengths to be the same, added sorting, changed the type of sort (INNER, LEFT OUTER etc.) but none of this helps, it still matches up policy numbers it should not match. I find this to be amazing if this hasn't been spotted before as surely it's a big flaw?

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the data types - it seems the comparison is done on the char(8). I have not seen it efore - and a test with two differnt char length columns did not match in my test.
There is no like comparison in join.

I think if you adjust the datatypes bioth to varchar(13) it should work.
Otherwise open a PMR.